# openssl -connect returns wrong certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, certificate

Here is my problem.
I have multiple domains hosted on one apache webserver. (Virtual Hosts)
Two of them (a.com and b.com) use ssl certificates.
I configured both with these commands:

```
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ABC.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ABC.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ABC.chain.crt
    SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2
```

When i try to connect via browser (chrome, Firefox, IE) it works fine and i get the right certificate.
But on android i got an exception: No peer certificate

Then i tried to test it with this command:

```
    openssl s_client -connect b.com:443
```

It returns me the certificate of the a.com.
Any suggestions what I've done wrong that i get the wrong certificate with openssl and android?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are probably multiple hosts on the same IP address and you need to use Server Name Indication (SNI) to access this site. To you SNI with `openssl s_client` use the `-servername` option, e.g.  `openssl s_client -connect b.com:443 -servername a.com`. As for android: according to https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html SNI is supported since 2.3 for HttpsURLConnection but not for Apache HTTP Client.